# Django search model by dictionary (also include between a range)

Tags: python, django, dictionary

Hello i'm having trouble trying to figure out how to handle this problem.

I have a dict like so(the data key can be anything, but value has 3 types of a string, int or a **dictionary** with **min** and **max** values):

```
{
   "city":5,
   "size":{
      "max":78693,
      "min":11202
   },
   "type":"rent",
   "ward":229,
   "price":{
      "max":43660474485,
      "min":7660026858
   },
   "street":1853,
   "district":20,
   "frontend":{
      "max":90,
      "min":18
   },
   "direction":"ne"
}
```

Right now what i'm trying to do is to search a model using filter following the values of the above dictionary, The problem is i don't know how to handle ,if a key has a **min** and **max** then i have to find between it's range in the filter.

I know that you can search by dict with the following :

```
models.objects.filter(**my_dict)
```

But how do i handle special conditions like **min** and **max** range in the filter ?

I'm looking to output like this(the field name follow the key of the dictionary):

```
models.objects.filter(city=5, size__range(min, max), type="rent",... other keys and values)
```

Thank for reading

Comment: What's the model look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest thing comes to my mind is to modify your dict to get dict which django model could use:

```
query_dict = {}
for k, v in my_dict.items():
     if type(v) is dict:
        query_dict[f'{k}__range'] = (v['min'], v['max'])
     else:
        query_dict[k] = v

query_dict # {'city': 5, 'size__range': [11202, 78693], 'type': 'rent', 'ward': 229, 'price__range': [7660026858, 43660474485], 'street': 1853, 'district': 20, 'frontend__range': [18, 90], 'direction': 'ne'}
```

There maybe more interesting solution though

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Comment: oh you should change the bracker [] to () since __range only accept that

Comment: @LinhNguyen changed